# Comic Sans on our website

Tags: html, css, fonts, webfonts

I'm getting sporadic reports of users seeing our website with the `Comic Sans` font.  This is obviously highly undesirable.

We use the `Lobster` Google web font which I strongly suspect is the one being rendered as `Comic Sans`.

Our homepage is http://www.scirra.com, can anyone tell me why it's falling back to `Comic Sans` for some people?

Comment: Not an answer... but do you have any other fonts listed for the Font-Family of that particular CSS rule?  If so, the fallback ought to be on one of the alternative font-family fonts, right?

Comment: @Summea we don't have any fallbacks listed, I'm just wondering why it would pick Comic Sans as I can't see it defined anywhere

Comment: Which part is falling back to Comic Sans? I mean menu, footer etc.

Comment: I have a hunch that it's picking Comic Sans because it's not a "regular default" serif, monospace, or sans-serif font.  It might be falling under a "Fantasy" type of font rule... and thus is being rendered with Comic Sans.  Not sure, though, so it's not an real answer. ;)

Comment: Always list fallbacks; especially with web fonts!  Get the users' operating systems and browsers.  If you know the IP, you can scan through the server logs for the matching user agents.  These will be invaluable in reproducing the problem.

Comment: I actually just got this in an email: "Wes, please change the default font to Comic Sans for the entire site." Wish I was kidding.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's because your font stack reads:

```
font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
```

[Comic Sans is a `cursive` family font](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/fonts.en.html). So if lobster fails to load from the google font api, comic sans is a valid fallback font.

Personally, I have nothing good to say about the viability of Google Font API, so I would recommend you use [@font-face](http://www.font-face.com/) to achieve your desired affect.

edit: woah, I just took a look at your web page and realized what i was looking at. So, on a personal note I'd just like to say I've used the scirra free edition to help me learn some stuff with the Canvas and I think it's an awesome product, so if you're a member of the team I just wanted to say thanks.

Comment: :/ ? Google Font API uses @font-face.

Comment: A better stack might be `Lobster, 'Monotype Corsiva', serif`.  Corsivia is a fairly close match, and a good enough fall back.  It's also available [about 83%](http://www.codestyle.org/css/font-family/sampler-Cursive.shtml) of the time

Comment: @iambriansreed that is correct, but they host the files remotely. I suppose it would have been better for me to say I recomend hosting the file on the server.

Comment: Yes, after shopping for fonts at Google, I always download them, generate stylesheets with Font Squirrel (the licenses allow this) and put them on my server.

Comment: @ChrisSobolewski Isn't using the files on Google's CDN better?

Comment: In theory a CDN is always better for this sort of thing. However, I have had nothing but problems with google's webfont service, and this question just illustrates that it isn't just me who has issues with fonts refusing to display intermitently.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!  And yes I'm part of the 2 man team :)  Thanks for the compliments!

Comment: To those reading in post-2012 times, Google's Font service is a lot more reliable now, use that instead of hosting it on your server, it'll potentially save you bandwidth (you as in the server) and provide more stability with the fonts